# Stop CMD opening when bat file launched

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, exe

I have this code

```
start /b error.vbs
```

When I run it, a CMD opens for half a second, then it runs. How would I remove or hide the CMD?

Comment: can you share your vbs script?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?23l33k87abu842g

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a batch file to launch a VBScript script. Just run the `.vbs` file directly with with `wscript.exe` (if you don't want the console). For example:

```
wscript error.vbs
```

Comment: Basically I just need to get an EXE file which runs teh error.vbs

Comment: You don't need to "get" anything. `wscript.exe` is the exe file that runs .vbs VBScript files. It is built into the OS already.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Um, double-click on the `.vbs` file in Windows Explorer?